# Can $\frac{x-c}{x} = \frac{y-c}{y}e^{-\frac{(x/y)-1}{(x/y)+1}}$ be solved explicitly for $x$ and $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, systems-of-equations

where $c>0$ and $x,y \geq 0$.

Is there an explicit way (closed form) to solve the equation in the title?

I believe the answer is that it must be that $x=y$, at least according to my logic below, but I am wondering if a closed form solution can be obtained.

---

My approach is as follows:
Suppose there is a solution with $x>y$, then $e^{-\frac{(x/y)-1}{(x/y)+1}} <1$, which means that the $ \frac{y-c}{y}e^{-\frac{(x/y)-1}{(x/y)+1}}< \frac{y-c}{y}$

But since $\frac{y-c}{y}== \frac{x-c}{x}$ IFF $x=y$, then  for $$\frac{y-c}{y}e^{-\frac{(x/y)-1}{(x/y)+1}} == \frac{x-c}{x}$$  requires $y>x$, **a contradiction**

A similar argument shows that there cannot be a solution with $y>x$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Using the substitution $$x=ty$$ we get
$$ty-c=(ty-ct)e^{-\frac{t-1}{t+1}}$$ this can be solved for $y$:
$$y={\frac {c}{t} \left( t{{\rm e}^{-{\frac {t-1}{t+1}}}}-1 \right) 
 \left( {{\rm e}^{-{\frac {t-1}{t+1}}}}-1 \right) ^{-1}}
$$
and you have also an equation for $$x$$ with the parameter $$t$$

Comment: If we use the substitution $x=ty$ aren't we assuming that $x$ is a linear function of $y$? For what reason are we allowed to make this assumption (or, if we can tell that it must be true, how can we tell? because it is not obvious to me).

Comment: Yes, you will get a parameter solution of your equation, you can use also another substitution: $$x=\sqrt{t}y$$ or so.

Comment: I guess I do not understand this solution method. Basically I have 2 questions: 1) How do we find $t$ here? The equation for $x$ is just $t$ times the equation for $y$. And i was under the impression that it must be that $t=1$, but perhaps I am wrong about that? and 2) Why can we just **assume** a parameter relationship between $x$ and $y$. Specifically, what if I assume some wrong form, like $x=t^2y + t -2$ (That is some random choice). I don't see how the steps in your answer wouldn't apply to that case, but **if that form is not correct, I imagine I should not find a solution...?**

Comment: Or are we perhaps simply saying that, **if** $x=ty$ then $y$ has the form given (and $x$ is $t$ times what you wrote for $y$), and we can let $t$ be any real number?

Comment: @user106860 What you have is a parametrization $x(t)$, $y(t)$. That's all.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I see. Another question, if $t=1$, then according to the above we have that $y=0/0$. But there are solutions where $x=y$, so why do we get that $y=0/0$?